# project template with MVC,EF, WCF, Repository, UoW, DI, loger?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, entity-framework

I want to start a project. Can you please guide me if a open source template is available which is suitable for small-medium applications and not over complex.

I want something with MVC, EF, WCF, Repository , UOW and DI pattens, test project and a error loger.

Please advice.

Comment: whats the purpose / **objective** of your project ?

Comment: Thanks @Yasser. it is initially a web application with mvc3 and later may have other clients as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first time that you work with ASP.NET MVC 3?  There are many tutorials online and sample applications that you can work through.  99% of these sample applications implement what you are looking for.  Work through applications so that you can learn, you are going to have to invest in some time to understand this a little better.  You can go and search [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/), there are tons of applications that you can download and work through the source code.

A project that helped me alot was `Kigg`.  Very well written code.  [Check it out on Codeplex](http://kigg.codeplex.com/).